# Reusing prepared statement generates segmentation fault

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have to make a prepared statement that is a call to a stored procedure, and I need to loop through an array, calling the procedure for each element in the array. So I would like to take advantage of the efficiency that you can set the statement up and then run it multiple times, just sending the value to insert.

However, when I do this, I get, not a php error but a browser error:

> This page isn’t working
>   localhost didn’t send any data.
>   ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

The apache2 logs show that there was a segmentation fault.

I want to do this:

```
$sql = $this->conn->prepare("call add_instrument(?, @instrument_id)");

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($new_instrument_names)-1; $i++) {
    $sql->bind_param("s", $new_instrument_names[$i]);
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->store_result();
    $sql->bind_result($this->new_instrument_ids[]);
    $sql->fetch();
}

$sql->close();
```

But the above generates the segmentation fault.

So I have to do this instead, putting the prepared statement inside the loop so that it happens for every item in the $new_instrument_names array :

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($new_instrument_names)-1; $i++) {
    $sql = $this->conn->prepare("call add_instrument(?, @instrument_id)");
    $sql->bind_param("s", $new_instrument_names[$i]);
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->store_result();
    $sql->bind_result($this->new_instrument_ids[]);
    $sql->fetch();

    $sql->close();
}
```

Could this be a bug in php7 or is there something wrong with my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$name = ""; //variable to bind your statement with
$response = ""; // get results
$sql = $this->conn->prepare("call add_instrument(?, @instrument_id)");
$sql->bind_param("s", $name);
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($new_instrument_names)-1; $i++) {
    $name = $new_instrument_names[$i];
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->store_result();
    $sql->bind_result($response);
    while ($sql->fetch())
        array_push($this->new_instrument_ids,$response);
}
$sql->close();
$this->conn->close(); //close the mysqli connection too
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but putting the bind_param outside the loop still generates the segmentation fault unfortunately.

Comment: @Alex, putting the 'bind_param' was only for performance improvement. Because I didn't have the same table as yours, I only changed the query sting and it worked for me, sorry It didn't work for you.

Comment: firstly, I don't know if it is relevant but the stored procedure call will only return one row, one single value. But most importantly, I use similar code elsewhere in my project and having both the prepare and the bind param outside the loop works, but then two or three different times I do this, it makes the segmentation fault. So I need to try your solution out on other bits of my project and will report back to you !

Comment: UPDATE: I updated from php7 to php7.3 - no difference. I went back over my code and changed it all to have both the prepare and bind_param functions outside of the loop. Only one out of about 7 sql statements now create the segmentation fault. I looked at many ways how the one that doesn't work is different from the ones that do, but I can't find any - still a mystery.